# Using JavaScript to search current webpage html for strings

Tags: javascript

I am currently using an [Axiom.ai](https://axiom.ai) bot to scrape other data from a webpage, and I would like to be able to use JavaScript to scrape some data that is not displayed numerically.

This is what I’d like to do:
Search the current webpage for **html classes** that contain the following 3 values:

```
color-box weak bold
color-box neutral bold
color-box strong bold
```

There are 3 instances where this occurs within the webpage. I’d like to assign a letter to each instance and return the combination of all 3. For example in the large block of code below we have:

```
color-box strong bold
color-box strong bold
color-box weak bold
```

I’d like to `return` **'S'** for **strong**, **'N'** for **neutral**, and **'W'** for **weak**. So this example would be **‘SSW’**.

Here's the large block of code referenced above:

```html
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="analysis-items">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term shortTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Short-Term sentiment</span><span _ngcontent-run-c70="">2 weeks to 6 weeks</span></div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box strong bold">strong</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term midTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Mid-Term sentiment</span>
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="">6 weeks to 9 months</span>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box strong bold">strong</div>

</div>
</div>
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term longTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Long-Term sentiment</span>
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="">9 months to 2 years</span>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box weak bold">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">strong</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---->
</div>
```

[Axiom's JavaScript guide](https://axiom.ai/docs/write-javascript.html)

I am not very familiar with JavaScript, and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.querySelectorAll(.color-box)` to get each element, then filter each elements `classList` to only include the ones you care about, then map the result to the uppercase first letter of each of those classes:

```js
const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.color-box')).flatMap((el) => {
    return Array.from(el.classList).filter(c => ['strong', 'neutral', 'weak'].includes(c));
}).filter(el => el.length).map(el => el.slice(0,1).toUpperCase());

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="analysis-items">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term shortTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Short-Term sentiment</span><span _ngcontent-run-c70="">2 weeks to 6 weeks</span></div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box strong bold">strong</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term midTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Mid-Term sentiment</span>
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="">6 weeks to 9 months</span>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box strong bold">strong</div>

</div>
</div>
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="term longTerm">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="bold">Long-Term sentiment</span>
<span _ngcontent-run-c70="">9 months to 2 years</span>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="">
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box weak bold">weak</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">neutral</div>
<div _ngcontent-run-c70="" class="color-box muted">strong</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---->
</div>
```